# How To Upload Image to Shiny App From Dropdown

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to upload images to my shiny app, but seem to be stuck on a basic step. The images are in my `www` directory. I am able to implement a drop down option, and would like the user to select an image (e.g, `mouse.png`) which would upload said image. However, the image itself is not uploading.

[image]

This is my code, does anyone have any ideas?

```
library(shiny)


#create a box function
my.box <- function(title, obj) {
  box(
    title = title,
    status = "primary",
    solidHeader = TRUE,
    collapsible = TRUE,
    plotOutput(obj, height = "300px")
  )
}

# List of choices for selectInput
mylist <- list.files("~/APP/www/")
body <- dashboardBody(tableOutput("filtered_table"), 
                      
                      my.box("Table1", "Table1"))

#create dropbox
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #drop down box 
  selectInput(inputId ="gene",label = h3("Select an image from below"),choices = mylist), 
  
  #name of the plot. 
  mainPanel(plotOutput("image")) #NOT SURE WHAT TO PLACE HERE
)

#server function
server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  observeEvent(input$myFile, {
    inFile <- input$myFile
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return()
    file.copy(inFile$datapath, file.path("~/APP/www/", inFile$name) )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example from the [shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html), you can use `renderImage`/`imageOutput`. Note that I've adjusted the file paths a bit.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


#create a box function
my.box <- function(title, obj) {
    box(
        title = title,
        status = "primary",
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsible = TRUE,
        plotOutput(obj, height = "300px")
    )
}

# List of choices for selectInput
mylist <- list.files("./www")
body <- dashboardBody(tableOutput("filtered_table"), 
                      
                      my.box("Table1", "Table1"))

#create dropbox
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    #drop down box 
    selectInput(inputId ="gene",label = h3("Select an image from below"),choices = mylist), 
    
    #name of the plot. 
    mainPanel(imageOutput("image"))
)

#server function
server = shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
    output$image <- renderImage({
        filename <- normalizePath(file.path('www',
                                            input$gene))
        list(src = filename)
    }, deleteFile = FALSE)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I see what I was doing wrong. Thank you!